# Slack style title bar

Tags: electron

Slack on the Mac at least removed the title bar but still has the control buttons. How do I duplicate this effect? Is there an electron option I missing or did slack rollout there own control buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Electron by setting the [`titleBarStyle`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) option.

To use it:

```
var winObj = new BrowserWindow({
    titleBarStyle:   'hidden',
});
```

This will hide the title bar but still keep the traffic lights in the corner.

Here are different values for the `titleBarStyle` option:

`default`

- Results in the standard gray opaque Mac title bar.

`hidden` (Used in the example).

- Results in a hidden title bar and a full size content window, yet the title bar still has the standard window controls ("traffic lights") in the top left.

`hiddenInset`

- Results in a hidden title bar with an alternative look where the traffic light buttons are slightly more inset from the window edge.

See the docs for the [`BrowserWindow` options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) (search for `titleBarStyle`).

Comment: Lol traffic lights. I like that. Haven’t heard them called that before.

Comment: Hi @eleethesontai, how's it going? If my answer was what you were looking for don't forget to upvote and accept it :). Otherwise I'll be happy to help with any other problem you're facing.